# Using PHP to identify current page

Tags: php, url, conditional-statements

I have a series of PHP page, and I would like to use conditional logic to apply different rules to each page. Im not sure if my method is the best way to go about it, so I wanted to see if the community had any recommendations, as this doesn't feel like the best approach. Code Below:

```
<?php

     $nameurl = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

     if ($nameurl == "/fs/about.php"){
         echo "about page";
     }

     elseif ($nameurl == "/fs/index.php"){
         echo "home page";
     }
?>
```

Ideally, I would like to only use the filename (index.php or about.php) instead of having /fs/. Im not sure if there is another way of using $_SERVER with PHP but it seems like there might be a more efficient and reusable way of writing this. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
// get script name
$script     = explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$scriptname = $script[count($script) - 1];

switch ($scriptname) {
    case "index.php":
        // Something you only want to show on this page
    break;

    case "about.php":
        // Something you only want to show on this page
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To save a couple of lines of code, you could replace the multiple ifs with a switch:

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

```
$nameurl = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
switch ($nameurl) {
    case "/fs/about.php":
        echo "about page";
        break;
    case "/fs/index.php":
        echo "home page";
        break;
    default:
        echo "unknown page";
        break;
}
```

Makes it a little easier to add new cases in the future, but it's essentially doing the same thing...

There might be ways to make it more optimized, but I think if you start doing too much you lose the ability to easily understand what's happening in the code, so unless you comment what you're doing future people looking at your work will curse you. :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$nameurl = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '.php');
echo $nameurl, " page";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Answer (score 0):

You could try :

```
$currentFile = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$current_filename = explode('/', $currentFile);
```

or

```
$current_filename = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) .'php';
```